How to populate or edit a HTML content using TinyMce editor in reactjs
I am using TinyMce React editor to allow users to create, edit, and save content coming from a database. However, ever. I'm having challenges parsing the HTML content from my database back to the editor.
I used useRef from react to hold the initialization of the editor, according to the TinyMCE docs, then used the current to getContent which works, it gives me back what the user typed. However, using the useRef.current.setContent(myDatabaseContent).
But I get an error, cannot read properties of null (reading setContent)
Who has used TinyMCE and how did you use it to edit your content? or how did you load your content back into the editor?

Add the TinyMCE Editor component to your React component's render method. You can set the initial content using the value prop.
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Editor } from '@tinymce/tinymce-react';

function MyEditor() {
  const [content, setContent] = useState('<p>Initial content</p>');

  const handleEditorChange = (newContent, editor) => {
    setContent(newContent);
  };

  return (
    <Editor
      initialValue={content}
      apiKey="YOUR_API_KEY"
      init={{
        height: 500,
        menubar: false,
        plugins: [
          'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor',
          'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
          'insertdatetime media table paste code help wordcount'
        ],
        toolbar:
          'undo redo | formatselect | bold italic backcolor | \
          alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | \
          bullist numlist outdent indent | removeformat | help'
      }}
      onEditorChange={handleEditorChange}
    />
  );
}

export default MyEditor;


I forgot to mention that I created a text editor component. This is where I initialized TinyMCE. I'm using this component on three different pages. On some pages, I need to pass in the content I want to edit as props, while on others I don't.
